# Good in-depth books for precalc?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, soft-question

I'm trying to brush up on algebra and precalc to remember stuff I used to know and learn stuff I didn't get to. Trying to pass the accuplacer placement test and test into calculus, so im trying to learn college algebra.

Right now I have the Everything Guide to Algebra by Christopher Monahan but it's not very in-depth. Recommendations?

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a little bit of a better idea of where you think you are currently? I wouldn't want to insult you by offering too simplistic a book, nor stymy you by offering something too complicated. Looking over the outline for the Accuplacer test(http://www.collegeboard.com/student/testing/accuplacer/accuplacer-tests.html), I see it covers everything from arithmetic through basic college algebra.  Where do you think you fit on that spectrum, and which topics in particular do you feel confident or unsure about?

Comment: I want a book for basic college algebra @ Drew Christianson. Trying to test into calculus.

Comment: It's easier to help if you give us some idea of where you are currently.  You've taken algebra and precalc, what do you remember and what do you want to review?  You say the Everything Guide is not in-depth enough - what are your problems with it?  Needs more step-by-step?  Needs more proofs?  Needs more examples? I'm not aware of a universally prescribed College Algebra book, so anything I or someone else recommend is based on your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Carl allendoerfer's "Freshman Mathematics" is a nice review. More fun to read is the classic "What is Mathematics" by Richard Courant.